# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de una columna oculta de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito obtener los datos de la columna oculta del dataGridView. Se que para ocultarla lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
this.dataGridView.Columns["IdCliente"].Visible = false;
```

pero, ¿Cómo obtengo su valor para modificar datos?

Comment: Como resolviste el problema, tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 2):

Puedes acceder a los datos por medio del nombre de la columna de esta forma:

```
this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["IdCliente"].Value.ToString();
```

o

```
  //Donde x es el numero de fila.
  this.dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells["IdCliente"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda yo lo había intentado de esa forma pero como la columna esta oculta genera un error al querer obtener el dato alguna otra forma de intentarlo ??